# $\hat{\pi}(x) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{X_i}(x)$ as an approximation of distribution $\pi(x)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, monte-carlo

Given a probability distribution $\pi(x)$ over the linear space $\mathcal{X}$ and samples $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^N$ drawn from $\pi(x)$, there is an approximation $\hat{\pi}(x) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{X_i}(x)$ (e.g. see the development of MC/particle filtering techniques given [here](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~arnaud/doucet_johansen_tutorialPF.pdf)).

My understanding is that the expectation of any test function $\phi: \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ is approximated as $E[\phi(x)] \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \phi(X_i)$.  The author then says this expectation estimate is unbiased and has variance given by $\frac{1}{N} \left( \int \phi^2(x)\pi(x) dx - E[\phi(x)]^2  \right)$.

I don't understand the steps I need to take to derive the variance expression.

Comment: By independence, $Var[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \phi(X_i)] = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i=1}^N Var(\phi(X_i)) = \frac{1}{N^2}N\int \phi^2(x)\pi(x)dx$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get this -- I guess it's been a while since basic probability for me.  So that's for the case where $E[\phi(x)] = 0$, and otherwise you have the $- E[\phi(x)]^2$ term..